# IOS flutter build is not creating but it run on android

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build, app-store

Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        24.8s
Xcode build done.                                           69.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im
connect/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.
(XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Alamofire' from project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BSGridCollectionViewLayout' from
project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BSImageView' from project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project
'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from
project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project
'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'MobileVLCKit' from project
'Pods')
/Users/apple/Desktop/flutter/im connect/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
'flutter_downloader-FlutterDownloaderDatabase' from project 'Pods')

Comment: opening your project in xcode will clarify more about the errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your version of info.plist from 8.0 to 9.0.

After that run the follow comands inside the ios folder:

- flutter clean;
- flutter pub get;
- pod setup;
- pod install;
- flutter run;